# python path during development of a package

Tags: python, anaconda, pythonpath

Let's say my project structure looks like this:

```
app/
    main.py
    modules/
        __init__.py
        validation.py
        configuration.py
```

modules package contains reusable code.
main.py executes main application logic.

When I try this in main.py

```
from modules import validation
```

I get an error which says that import inside of the validation failed. Validation tries to import configuration and I get 'no module named configuration'

I am using Anaconda distribution on windows.

What is the best way of handling PYTHONPATH during development of the package ?

Is there a way to utilize virtualenv (or conda env) in order to get package, that is in development,on the PYTHONPATH without changing **sys.path** from the code ?

What is the preferred practice when developing a package ?

I've also tried adding modules (folder) package to the lib/site-packages but it still didn't work.

Comment: what is your module/__init__.py

Comment: What you're doing should work.  Is your `__init__.py` empty?  Assuming it is, then perhaps there's a problem with your import statement inside of `validation.py`?

Comment: my __init__.py is empty and validation is importing configuration with **import configuration** and then uses it like **configuration.app_config()** .... my main.py is importing validation with **from modules import validation**

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: It is a python 3.4, but, of course, I would like to use the most portable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your import in `validation.py` to:

```
from . import configuration
```

This is needed for Python 3 but also works with Python 2.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it when I get home